# Error: Could not find or load main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on my gui-less server. I've installed `android-sdk` package and it seems to be broken — there is no `tools/lib` directory, so `sdkmanager` doesn't work:

```
dpkg -L android-sdk
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/android-sdk
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/bin
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/proguard
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/proguard/bin
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/proguard/lib
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/android-sdk
/usr/share/doc/android-sdk/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/android-sdk/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/android-sdk/copyright
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/bin/e2fsck
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/bin/fsck.ext4
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/bin/mkfs.ext4
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/bin/resize2fs
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/bin/screenshot2
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/bin/tune2fs
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/proguard/bin/proguard
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/proguard/bin/proguardgui
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/proguard/lib/proguard.jar
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/proguard/lib/proguardgui.jar
/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/proguard/lib/retrace.jar
```

```
./sdkmanager 
Error: Could not find or load main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli
```

How to fix it without installing SDK manually?